# C# events for KeyUp and KeyDown across system

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, system

trying to write a program to flag a Key_up or Key_down event throughout the system, but I'm having a hard time with the implementation. I've seen a few posts on here that link to outdated articles on Global Hooks, but they are usually so old I cant get source code working, or theres really no explination of how it works.

I'm looking for some sort of implementation that's relitively simple (ie a library or DLL I can use, or if it's implemented by Visual Studio 2010 somewhere) as opposed to having several classes and files devoted to making a global hook.

The use of my code: I essentially want to extend the CTRL+C function to detect if CTRL is pressed, and if C and 1 are pressed (CTRL+C+1) I copy, but also store the copied text onto a notepad document.

So with that in mind it seems really extensive to design all this code only to hook onto the KeyDown/KeyUp that will be used for only 1 key

*if this question has been answered recently please link me and I can close/edit this to not be redundant*

Comment: I'm curious as well.  I've seen old articles just like you, but nothing "recent."

Comment: Looks too broad. Nothing really changed in this area for many years... so old ways are still there to use. Note that you *may* have  [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and should be looking for "clipboard viewer chain" and not "keyboard hooks".

Comment: thanks, also I'll be posting the solution for future use

Answer (score 1):

OK, so almost immediately after posting this I found the sollution by re-wording my search :/  sorry to be 'that guy' everyone. BUT in the spirite of helpfulness here is a link to a SUPER quick way to get global hotkeys in your application:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

this works for both creating new hotkeys and overriding old ones

Comment: Hmm, I've never come across that one.  Thanks for sharing.